# Error in subset.default(sos1, grepl(m, sos1)) : 'subset' must be logical

Tags: r

This code is producing

> Error in subset.default(sos1, grepl(m, sos1)) : 'subset' must be logical

`unik` contains `c("900-12004-2501-000", "900-12004-2510-000", "900-12005-0120-000")`

`sos1` contains `c("900-12004-2501-0008000FOX1 SFOX1", 900-12004-2510-0008000FOX1 SFOX1", 900-12005-0120-0008000FOX1 SFOX')`

Please Help

```
x <- nrow(miss)
unik <- unique(miss$Material.Number)
unik1 <- as.character(unik)
sos <- read.xlsx("trprod.xlsx", sheet = 1)
sos1 <- as.character(sos$Source.of.Supply)

output <- c()
for (i in 1:x) 
  {
    m <- (unik1[i])
    result <- subset(sos1, grepl(m, sos1))
    if (length(result) == 0 ){
      print('in if')
      output <- c(output, m)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second parameter of `subset` function needs to be logical and you have a `grepl()` function which doesn't return logical values.

Comment: `library(dplyr) result <- filter(sos1, grepl(m, sos1))`  I didint check it in my rstudio, try it out

Comment: @R18 `grepl()` does return a logical vector. @sap6370 please include a working data example in your question, done easily by pasting the output of `dput(miss$Material.Number[1:20)`.

Comment: You haven't defined `x`, so your loop might not be doing what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error message because your running variable `i` runs from 1 to `nrow(miss)`. Your vector `unik1`, however is shorter than `nrow(miss)`, due to the `unique` operator being applied to it. Hence, when `i` exceeds the length of `unik1`, the variable `m` inside your loop becomes `NA` and `grepl` returns a vector of `NA`s which is of class `int` not `logical`. That's where the error comes from.

You can either change `x` to `x <- length(unik1)` or - of you really need to loop over all rows of `miss` - change the `subset` operation to

```
result <- subset(sos1, as.logical(grepl(m, sos1)))
```